# Setting cell formatting only second row till user clicks?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am using a bit of code to make a cell color active which is red and white but for some reason when the user clicks on the cell it fires correctly and paints both cells based on a condition in another cell on the same row its a percentage yeild. But for some reason its only painitng the second row intially and I have no idea as to why.

I am using this in the following event

> private void dgUpdatesPrices_CellFormatting(object sender,
>   DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)

```
  /// </summary>
    public void checkSPSThreasholds(double _oldPrice, double _newPrice, DataGridViewRow dgr)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dgUpdatesPrices.Rows)

        {
            if (_priceListType == "SPS")
            {
                Double _percentage = calculatePercentageDiff(_oldPrice, _newPrice);
                dgr.Cells["SPercentage"].Value = _percentage.ToString();

                if (_percentage > 1.2)
                {
                    ValidateProducts _validateProduct = new ValidateProducts();

                    dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;

                    _validateProduct.ValidationMessage = "Product is above threshold, please adjust.";
                    if (dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value.ToStringOrEmpty() != "")
                    {
                        _validateProduct.price = Convert.ToDecimal(dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value);
                    }
                    _validateProduct.ValidationProduct = dgr.Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();
                    _validatePrices.Add(_validateProduct);
                }

                if (_percentage < 0.8)
                {
                    ValidateProducts _validateProduct = new ValidateProducts();

                    dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;

                    _validateProduct.ValidationMessage = "Product is below threshold, please adjust.";
                    if (dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value.ToStringOrEmpty() != "")
                    {
                        _validateProduct.price = Convert.ToDecimal(dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Value);
                    }
                    _validateProduct.ValidationProduct = dgr.Cells["Description"].Value.ToString();
                    _validatePrices.Add(_validateProduct);
                }

                if (_percentage == 0)
                {
                    dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                    dgr.Cells["NSPSPRICE"].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Based on what is in the percentage column it should paint both cells in new sps price it does once the user clicks in the above cell am I missing a repaint function.

[image]

You should see cause the percentage column shows the first percentage greater than 20 it should be coloured same as second row now when I click in the second cell it paints it fine is this a case full row select maybe interfering.

Comment: Thanks for the up vote does anybody no how I would stop this from hapening

Comment: It may be that you omitted some code for clarity sake, but what is the point of the `foreach (DataGridViewRow Row in dgUpdatesPrices.Rows)`; `Row` is never used.  You say that you are using the `CellFormatting` event, yet you are setting the `Style` of a particular cell.  This defeats the intent of the event.  You should be setting the `e.CellStyle` argument when the event is fired for a cell in the  `NSPSPRICE` column.  I suggest you read [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx).